# Relaciones en Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Actualmete estoy trabajando con 3 tablas.

Presupuesto: Que contiene el presupuesto Mensual de cada Tienda
Ventas_Full: Contiene las trasacciones de cada tienda
Date: Tabla de fechas

Lo que necesito mostrar en una tabla es el presupuesto diario acumulado ( Que obtengo calculando: Presupuesto Mensual / Dias del Mes * Dia actual, por ejemplo: $10.000 / 31 días de enero * 11 días )

Cual es el problema: Presupuestos y Ventas estan relacionadas por una columna llave, que contiene La Marca-Tienda-Mes , actualmente la relacion tal como se muestra en la imagen me funciona sin problemas, excepto por un detalle, si una TIENDA no contiene ventas a la fecha, al poner una tabla del presupuesto, este ignora a la tienda que no reporta ventas (no hay datos) y me da un valor menor al que quiero.

Ejemplo:

| Tienda | Ventas | Presupuesto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tienda 1 | $100 | $80 |
| Tienda 2 | $200 | $150 |
| Tienda 3 | - | - |
| TOTAL | $300 | $230 |

Que necesito:

| Tienda | Ventas | Presupuesto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tienda 1 | $100 | $80 |
| Tienda 2 | $200 | $150 |
| Tienda 3 | - | **$200** |
| TOTAL | $300 | **$430** |

Es decir, que aunque la llave no encuentre ningun match en la tabla de ventas, me muestre de igual forma ese presupuesto (Tienda 3 por un valor de $200)

Alguna idea de como lo podría realizar?

Gracias de Ante Mano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El modelo que presentas notiene buen aspecto. Para empezar la relación entre presupuestos y ventas no tiene sentido y menos con bidireccional.

El motor de Power BI funciona de forma eficiente en modelos de estrella, aquellos que tienen la/s tablas de hechos en medio y alrededor su relación con las tablas de dimensiones.

De esta forma debes tener una tabla de Presupuestos con el máximo nivel de detalle y a ella le relacionas la tabla de tiendas, la de marcas, la de empresa, la de fecha, etc. Y haces lo mismo con la tabla de Ventas, sin relacionarla con presupuesto.

Luego construyes las medidas:

```
Presupuesto = SUM(Presupuesto[Ppto Dia])
Venta = SUM(Ventas_FULL[Venta])
```

Una vez lo tienes bien relacionado, en los visuales (gráficos, tablas) te olvidas de los campos de las tablas de hechos (Presupuesto, Ventas_FULL) y solo  utilizas los campos de las tablas de dimensiones y las medidas.

Comment: Por lo que entendi, deberia tener una tabla de Marca, una tabla de Tiendas y empresa, a cada una de esas tablas debo relacionarla con la tabla de Presupuesto y de Ventas respectivamente, cada una por separado, y luego solamente utilizar las medidas?

Comment: Correcto, es la forma óptima para que evites problemas

Comment: Me funciono en un 90%, el unico problema que tengo, es que el presupuesto no se mueve con los filtros de fecha. Actualmente la tabla de Fecha esta relacionada con la de Ventas, al intentar relacionar con la de Presupuesto me dice que se creara una ambigüedad entre las tablas.

Comment: Debes asegurarte que la tabla de fechas contiene totos los valores posibles, aunque tenga más fechas que la de presupuestos y ventas, y sobre todo, que no contenga valores en blanco (null). También que las tres tablas comparten el mismo tipo de dato (Date, DateTime). Lo ideal es tener una tabla de fechas continuas, sin saltos de fechas, esto te permitirá luego tener medidas a partir del tiempo (acumulados, trimestres, etc)